# No. of components in graph

Tags: math

A graph has 20 vertices and 6 edges. Is the no of components in this graph always 14?
If not, what is the max and min no of components in the graph?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about graph theory.

Comment: thats why the tag is graph

Comment: You'd probably be better off asking on http://math.stackexchange.com, or another sister site.

Comment: Are you looking for Euler's formula? (If you count "faces" also, I think you are.)  Try http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/eulers-formula.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the graph has any cycles, no. You may have more than 14 components.

[image]

For example, the above graph has 20 vertices, 6 edges, and 16 components.

For *acyclic* graphs, the number of components equals the number of vertices minus the number of edges. This is apparent from the recursive formula:

```
function num_components(vertices, edges){
    //base case: we have nothing but unconnected vertices. 
    if (edges == 0){
        //Each one is its own component.
        return vertices;
    }
    else{
        //Adding a single edge to an acyclic graph
        //reduces the number of components by one.
        return num_components(vertices, edges - 1) - 1;
    }
}
```